# Driving in France with a foreign license after residency has expired

Tags: france, driving-license

I have been a resident in France with a valid titre de séjour for 2.5 years. I never exchanged my US (New York) driver's license, so I stopped driving after 1 year. Soon, my titre de séjour will expire, and I will relocate to another EU country (Germany).

I plan to come back to France as a tourist approximately 1 month after my titre de séjour expires. [Other](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-long-term-visa-ends-in-schengen-countr) [answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/can-i-start-a-tourist-schengen-visit-after-my-long-term-schengen-visa-is-over) suggest that this will be no problem as far as coming in as a tourist. My question is, since I will be entering France as a tourist, does that mean I will be allowed to drive again? I can find nothing on the French web pages about this specific case, and I'm hoping this means that a tourist is a tourist and I will have no trouble, but it would be nice if someone knew for sure as the penalty if I'm wrong could be quite severe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the right to come as a tourist (*court séjour*), this is the rule that apply :

[Conduire en France avec un permis non européen](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1459#situation1)

*Si vous venez en France pour un court séjour (pour des vacances par exemple), vous pouvez conduire avec votre permis. Il doit être valide et être rédigé en français ou accompagné d'une traduction officielle en français ou d'un permis international.*

So you will be allowed to drive if your US driver's license is still valid in the US, and is either written in French, associated with an international driver's license or associated with an official translation.